# Does "DDR4L" memory exist?

Tags: memory

I cannot find any infomation about that on reliable sites, does DDR4 only have one version(no low voltage version)?

Answer (score 3):

According to an [unreliable site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) (Wikipedia) and a [most reliable site](https://www.jedec.org/category/technology-focus-area/main-memory-ddr3-ddr4-sdram) (JEDEC):

- Regular DDR4 runs at approximately 1.2V – not 1.5V – so it is already even lower than DDR3L.
- DDR4L (running at even lower 1.05V) allegedly was in the plans at least until 2014, but so far no such specification has been published [by JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/document_search?search_api_views_fulltext=DDR4), so officially it does exist at this moment.
- LPDDR4 and LPDDR4X (Low-power DDR4) *does* exist (1.12V and 0.6V respectively), but it seems to be meant as soldered-in memory for embedded systems, not SODIMMs.