# Can I combine DDR4 and DDR4-L in my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire, ramdisk

I have ACER Laptop with 4GB **DDR4** 2133MHZ RAM. I want to add another 8GB RAM. However, I cannot find DDR4 8GB RAM in 2133MHZ in my local area. However, I found 8GB **DDR4-L** 2133MHZ RAM. Can I use it in my additional slot. I mean, will it be a problem to combine both **DDR4** and **DDR4-L** RAM both 2133MHZ. (I heard the only difference is in the voltage consumption, however, I'm asking in case they don't match and lead to crashes.)

Comment: DDR4L RAM might not actually exist - do you have the operating voltage specs for both your DDR4 and supposed DDR4L stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine both DDR4 and DDR4L memory, but you may notice degraded performance in the DDR4L stick compared to the regular DDR4 (because, as you said, it uses less power) but running both types in conjunction will work fine.

For the best performance, I'd recommend buying another DDR4 stick over DDR4L.

**Edit:** As @Mokubai said in the comments, DDR4L can also apparently support working at regular DDR4 voltages as well, making them both basically the same thing.

This other part isn't relevant to your specific situation (as your motherboard already supports regular DDR4), but I'll leave it here for reference - a motherboard that only supports DDR4L RAM will not work with DDR4 RAM as it won't be able to provide a sufficient voltage required by the regular DDR4 stick. So you can use DDR4L RAM on a DDR4 motherboard, but not the other way around.

Comment: I think that DDR4L is capable of using less power by working at a lower voltage but should also support working at the normal DDR4 voltage and so be essentially the same. DDR4L will work either as DDR4L or DDR4. Basically you can use DDR4L in any motherboard but normal DDR4 cannot work on a processor/motherboard that only supports DDR4L as DDR4 does not support the lower voltage. Other than the voltage the performance should be nearly the same.

Comment: @Mokubai I didn't know that, thanks! I'll update my answer to include that, Just out of interest, where did you find out DDR4L could operate at regular DDR4 voltage?

Comment: I might be wrong, I'm not sure now. I know what I said is correct for DDR3 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#DDR3L_and_DDR3U_extensions) but I cannot actually find anything about DDR4L. There is LPDDR4, but that is different I think. Sorry.

Comment: DDR4L might just be actual DDR4 that has been mislabelled... https://superuser.com/questions/1498605/does-ddr4l-memory-exist

Comment: @Mokubai Yeah... I was just researching it as well and now I'm really not sure. I've heard the term DDR4L used in the past, which is why I answered the question, but there's really not a lot online giving proper info or specifications about it. My understanding was that DDR4L only used a marginally less amount of power.

Comment: Yeah I can find LPDDR which is apparently intended for embedded systems, achieves low power by sacrificing bandwidth and operates at 1.05V instead of 1.2V. I found https://digitalbridgebd.com/product/g-skill-ripjaws-8gb-ddr4-l-2133-bus-notebook-ram/ but it operates at 1.2V which is the normal DDR4 voltage so the "L" is irrelevant or wrong. It's neither LPDDR4 nor DDR4"L"...

Comment: I have encountered on SU a case of using DDR4 on a DDR4L motherboard. This worked, just not with full RAM. Seems like the motherboard was limited in the total amount of voltage that it could supply, so it could support only 2 sticks instead of the available 4.